# How can I use text-align-last except when I have only one line of text?

Tags: css, text-align

I would like to align text to the center, but last line to the left:

```css
section {
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: left;
}
```

It works well, but what if there is only one line? In this case, I would like to align text to the center, which doesn't work, because the first line is also last line. Is there any selector for elements with only multiline text or selector for first line (not pseudo-element `:first-line`)?

Live Example:

```css
section {
  text-align: center;
  text-align-last: left;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<strong>This works:</strong>
<section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam aliquam turpis consectetur diam fringilla, vel ultrices sapien bibendum. Maecenas pulvinar in nisl at mattis. Duis nisi risus, rhoncus sit amet ornare malesuada.</section>

<strong>Next line should be centered (something like text-align-first?):</strong>
<section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</section>
```

Comment: give fiddle or code?

Comment: The code is right there, and it's fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: I have added the example code to the first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way to override `text-align-last` for when a block container has only one formatted line and `text-align` is `center`.

The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#text-align-last-property) says that `text-align-last` can be overridden, but only when `text-align` is `start end`. This does not seem to apply to any of the other values for `text-align`.

There are no selectors for elements with zero, one, or n formatted lines, nor is there a `::last-line` counterpart to `::first-line`. So it seems you're out of luck doing this with pure CSS. You're going to have to use a script to identify `section` elements with only one line (i.e. `section` elements whose text isn't wrapping), attach a class name to those elements, and apply `text-align-last: center` (or `auto`) to them.

Comment: *You're going to have to use a script to identify section elements with only one line* How would I do that?

Comment: @torazaburo: That's probably outside the scope of this question. (Just another way of saying "I don't know.")

Comment: See the answer below,,,

Comment: @xianshenglu: I'm aware of it.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I invented another solution. I will set all the elements `display: inline-block;` and place them into the container with `text-align: center;`. If there are multiple lines, nothing will change. But if there is only one line, `.child` will have smaller width and is centered.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-align-last: left;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
    <strong>This works:</strong>
    <section class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam aliquam turpis consectetur diam fringilla, vel ultrices sapien bibendum. Maecenas pulvinar in nisl at mattis. Duis nisi risus, rhoncus sit amet ornare malesuada.</section>
    <strong>Next line should be centered</strong>
    <section class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</section>
</section>
```

Comment: That was genius!

Answer (score 2):

Overriding `text-align-last` on the desired element with the selector `::first-line` does the job.

```css
section {
  text-align: center;
  text-align-last: left;
  width: 300px;
}
section::first-line {
  text-align-last: center;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<strong>This works:</strong>
<section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam aliquam turpis consectetur diam fringilla, vel ultrices sapien bibendum. Maecenas pulvinar in nisl at mattis. Duis nisi risus, rhoncus sit amet ornare malesuada.</section>

<strong>Next line should be centered (something like text-align-first?):</strong>
<section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</section>
```

Comment: Nice trick. The only problem - it doesn't make friends with `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

I found using width: `max-content, max-width:100%`, and centering the element to work very well. If it's less than one line, the element will shrink to the size of the line and will be centered by a `margin: 0 auto;` If it extends beyond one line, it will stretch the element to the point where it hits the `max-width:100%` rule and then continue to the next line. Now that the block is at the max width, the text inside will follow the `text-align` rule.

```css
.justify_unless_one_line{
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: max-content;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.container{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div class='container'>
 <h2>Single Line</h2>
  <p class="justify_unless_one_line">
      This is an example of one line
  </p>
  <h2>Many Lines</h2>
  <p class="justify_unless_one_line">
      This is an example of many lines. This is an example of many lines. This is an example of many lines. This is an example of many lines. This is an example of many lines. This is an example of many lines.
  </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -4):

first line selector `text-align: center;`

```
section:nth(1){
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: :nth(1)? Where did you pull that from?

Comment: Please provide a running snippet.